# AppDelegate.m file not showing in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

On the left hand side you can see the Xcode is not showing `AppDelegate.m` file but in my project's directory, I can see it in Finder.

[image]

Comment: so add it to the project

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Add means? Copy and paste it in the Runner folder in the Xcode?

Comment: In Xcode it is File-> Add Files to 'Project Name'